# What relevant differences are there between anonymous and predefined classes in Java?

Tags: java, class-design, anonymous-types

I have a large tree-like data structure of objects which behave mostly identical but differ in one or two methods that calculate some keys used to navigate through the structure. The divergent behaviour depends on where the objects are in the structure.

I was starting out with an abstract base class and have several subclasses that implement each type of behaviour. This gives me around ten subtypes which are a) hard to name intelligently and b) look a little unwieldy in my project's source folder, both because they are so similar.

I would prefer having a single factory class that doles out instances of anonymous subclasses on the fly. This would give me a lot of flexibility and open the door for a lot of nice improvements, such as sharing data and parametrizing stuff and would look a lot cleaner in my code structure. However, the whole thing is very sensitive to memory footprint and memory access time, and I'd have lots of these objects. Do I have to consider any disadvantages or pecularities of anonymous classes?

Comment: Anonymous classes are not static. This can result in different gc behavior as the "parent" class cannot be garbage collected indepently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like non-static inner classes, anonymous classes have a hidden reference to the class they're defined in, which can cause problems if you use serialization and of course prevent objects of the outer class from being eligible for GC - but that's unlikely to be a problem if you do it in a single factory class.

Comment: He could use static inner classes as well.  This would solve the reference problem as well as the "organization" issue the OP mentioned.  He would still have to name them well (or not) though.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous classes are not different than named classes.

But yes, having many objects can impact your memory footprint, and performance (garbage-collection).

---

From what you tell, I wonder if it would be possible to split your class in two parts:

1. All the constant methods in one class (no subclass of this class).
2. All variable methods (see later) are encapsulated in a Position interface. You can have a few classes that implement it. The objects of these classes would have no state, so they can be shared instances which is excellent for performance and memory).

> Variable methods : calculate some keys depending on the position in the structure.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned an anonymous inner class usually has a hidden reference to the class in which it is declared. However, you can eliminate this by declaring the anonymous class from inside a static method (simple, and not perfectly obvious).

The major disadvantage to this technique is that the classnames seen in jars will be numbered (like "MyClass$0.class") and not easily identifiable in stacktraces (except of course by using the line numbers) and without toString() methods not easily identifiable in your own println statements.

Declaring static inner classes is a great technique. It will eliminate all these disadvantages and keep your file hierarchy compact. Also consider making these inner classes private or final unless you need to extend them.

Answer (score 1):

A class is a class. It doesn't matter whether it's a "top-level" classes, a regular inner class, a local inner class, or an anonymous inner class.

Non-static inner classes, or inner classes that access private members of their enclosing class will have a tiny bit of extra code in them. To non-static inner classes, the compiler adds a member variable that references the enclosing instance. If an inner class accesses any private members of the enclosing class, the compiler will synthesize an accessor in the enclosing class with "package-private" (default) accessibility.

Comment: but you forgot to mention any memory footprint implications (if any)